# How do you run a Helper / Controller method using Clockwork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork

I'm sure I've got the completely wrong of the stick with regard to how Clockwork works. Basically I'm got a number of methods that exist within a Controller, as they're currently triggered by navigating to their relevant routes. I'm trying to get clockwork to run these methods, but I get a number of errors, including No Method Errors.

I've had a look around but can't seem to find anything to point me in the right direction. If this isn't the way to do it, where do I need to put my action logic in order to execute it using Clockwork?

This is my clock.rb file at the moment, which results in a NoMethodError

```
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

include Clockwork

handler do |job|
  puts "Running #{job}"
end

every(3.minutes, 'application.tester') { ApplicationController::tester }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is horrible OO practice, let Rails call controller methods. Whatever code you have in these controller methods move to its own class or module and call them in a Rake task. Then proceed to call that rake task in Clockwork.